# I want to create IdName property like className in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am new in JS and 
I want to add Id to any tag using idName that I create.

```
var x= Element;
x.prototype.idName= function(value){ this.id= value}
```

This works, but I want to write like className

Example:

```
this.className= "class value"
```

I want:

```
this.idName= "id value"
```

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set a `setter` for the `Object.prototype` and check if the element has a tag name when the property is setted:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'idName', {
    set : function(value) {
        if(typeof this.tagName !== 'undefined') {
            this.id = value;
        }
    }
});
```

```js
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'idName', {
 set : function(value) {
  if(typeof this.tagName !== 'undefined') {
   this.id = value;
  }
 }
});

var element = document.querySelector('.myelement');
element.idName = 'foo';

console.log(document.getElementById('foo'));
```

```html
<div class="myelement"></div>
```